# export 'x' (imported as 'y') was not found in 'z'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know, I know there are lots of questions about this topic out there and I read them as much as I could but believe me non of them gave me my answer.

my code is simple: I have a file named data.js like this:

```
export const data = [
  {
    title: "HOME",
    icon: <MdHome />,
  },
  //and some more objects like this
];

export const portfolioData = [
  {
    title: "NetFlix movie",
    path: "",
  },
  //and some more objects like this
];

export const skillsData = [
  {
    title: "photoshop",
    percentage: "90",
  },
//and some more objects like this
];

export const test = [
  { name: "x", lastname: "y" },
  //and some more object like this
];
```

so I have four named export here . In another folder I have another file and i want to use these data that exported.

here is the code for imports :

```
import { data } from "../utils/data";
import { portfolioData } from "../utils/data";
import { test } from "../utils/data";
import { skillsData } from "../utils/data";
```

the problem is that now, when i want to use these imports. just two of them (data and portfolioData) works as normal but the last two imports gives me error :

```
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Homepage.js 59:37-41
    export 'test' (imported as 'test') was not found in '../utils/data' (possible exports: data, portfolioData)
ERROR in ./src/pages/Homepage.js 59:37-41
export 'skillsData' (imported as 'skillsData') was not found in '../utils/data' (possible exports: data, portfolioData)
```

how could it be possible that in a same file with same exports method and with the same import method as you can clearly see, two of them work and two of them dont work?
and the weird thing is that if I change portfolioData name to for example "someName" and then import it as import {someName} from "../utils/data", now it stops working anymore.

Comment: There's a typo: `skilsData`. I assume it's the same for `test`, maybe a special character or something. Double-check your spelling. It works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type-forked-t1nd7k?file=/src/pages/Homepage.js

Comment: I would expect this is an updating issue? Like your server isn't showing the newest version of ../utils/data?

Comment: yeah exactly . @asdf3.14159 as you said it was an updating issue. I tried to refresh the server and now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Could you try importing all those with a single line and see if it works? Something like this:

```
import { data, portfolioData, skillsData, test } from '../utils/data';
```

While at it, ensure the data file containing the exports is saved as this could also be an issue when new exports are added and the file is not saved.

Comment: Thank you. it was really weird for me but it was just a server error. I just refreshed the server and now its working. the most strange thing is that I refreshed my server already and no change. but this second time it suddenly worked again . anyway wasted couple of hours of mine